# melhor maneira de usar if else

Tags: python

Queria saber se esse é um bom método para resolver esse problema:

> Crie um programa que leia o ano de nascimento de um atleta e mostre
> sua categoria, de acordo com a idade:
>
> - Até 9 anos: MIRIM
> - Até 14 anos: INFANTIL
> - Até 19 anos: JÚNIOR
> - Até 25 anos: SÊNIOR
> - Acima de 25 anos: MASTER'''

```
from datetime import date    
cl = ' '
ano = int(input('ano de nascimento: '))
idade = date.today().year-ano
if idade in range(0,10):
    cl = 'MIRIM'
elif idade in range(11,15):
    cl = 'INFANTIL'
elif idade in range(15,20):
    cl = 'JÚNIOR'
elif idade in range(20,26):
    cl = 'SÊNIOR'
else:
    cl = 'MASTER'
print(f'idade: {idade}\nclassificação: {cl}')
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Qualquer ano acima de 2022 vai resultar em um `idade` negativo, que vai cair na condição `MASTER`. O ideal neste caso é verificar na última condição se `idade > 26`.

Comment: O problema de fazer assim é que se algum intervalo mudar (por exemplo, se o limite para MIRIM passar a ser 8 anos), vc precisa mudar dois ranges (no caso, o primeiro e o segundo). O mesmo vale se surgir uma categoria intermediária (por exemplo, até 22 anos é outra classificação), tem que adicionar essa e mudar o range seguinte. Fora o problema da idade negativa que já mencionaram. Eu prefiro fazer assim: https://ideone.com/ZKLDQP (qualquer mudança nos limites só exige alteração em um dos `if`'s)

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma mais performática seria:

```
from datetime import date    
cl = ' '
ano = int(input('ano de nascimento: '))
idade = date.today().year-ano
if idade >= 0:
    if idade < 11:
        cl = 'MIRIM'
    elif idade < 15:
        cl = 'INFANTIL'
    elif idade < 20:
        cl = 'JÚNIOR'
    elif idade < 26:
        cl = 'SÊNIOR'
    else:
        cl = 'MASTER'
    print(f'idade: {idade}\nclassificação: {cl}')
else:
    print(f'Ano de nascimento {ano} inválido.')
```